# How to save key corresponding to every value of a dictionary in a list in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has only two keys: "f" and "m". Both these keys have 1000 unique values in it. Therefore total 2000 values corresponding to "f" and "m"

How can create a list of length 2000 having key's stored in it i.e. "f" and "m" for all 2000 values of dict ?

Edit: I wanted output to be a list like ['f','f','f',........(1000 "f" in list ),'m','m'.......(1000 "m" in list)]

Comment: Can you show small example of your desired output?

Comment: `d['f'] + d['m']`

Comment: @AvinashRaj this gives all the values related to the key. I want for every value, their corresponding key in a list.

Comment: If `d` was your dict `[k for k, v in d.items() for x in v]`.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Your question is not appropriate for understanding. Please tell what you have tried and where are you facing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want something like this ?

```
dummy_dict={'f':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'m':[14,13,11,43,11,2,11,1,4,34]}

print([key for key,value in dummy_dict.items() for _ in range(len(value))])
```

output :

```
['f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm', 'm']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped !!

Answer (score 1):

Let's create/simulate a dictionary 'foo' containing 2 keys 'f' and 'm'. The value stored against each of these keys is a list of 1000 elements.

```
>>> foo = {'f': ['x']*1000, 'm': ['y']*1000}
>>> len(foo['f'])
1000
>>> len(foo['m'])
1000
>>>
```

Now, let's initialize an empty list 'bar' to store the desired output.

```
>>> bar = []
>>>
```

A list can be extended to include elements from other list in the original list. Let's use this to extend 'bar' to contain as many 'f' as the number of elements in foo['f'].

```
>>> bar.extend(['f']*len(foo['f']))
>>>
```

Repeat the same for foo['m']

```
>>> bar.extend(['m']*len(foo['m']))
>>>
```

Now, 'bar' is a list of 2000 elements - first 1000 elements are 'f' and next 1000 elements are 'm'. Verifying the values against indices 0, 999 (first 1000 elements) and 1000, 1999 (remaining 1000 elements) prove the same.

```
>>> len(bar)
2000
>>> bar[0]
'f'
>>> bar[999]
'f'
>>> bar[1000]
'm'
>>> bar[1999]
'm'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulRooney. I've updated the answer to include the explanations.